# Choppy flash video playback, 'settings' disabled for Flash as well

Tags: flash

I'm using 12.04 classic Gnome. Lately, I have been experiencing choppy flash video playback. In youtube as well as in other sites. I tried installing flash-aid plugin for firefox and executed its wizard who installed another version of flash player player for me. But to no avail.

One of the answers that I found was to 'disable hardware acceleration'. Unfortunately, the 'settings' option while right-clicking is greyed out as well. I was not able to follow what they recommended in the following link:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/891337

How can I remove the choppiness of the flash video playback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running compiz. I uninstalled it and on a restart, found that the choppiness had gone as well as the settings was clickable.

But when I tried installing compiz again, I could not reproduce the video choppiness nor the 'unclickability' of settings.